# Can't use clock_gettime() as a stopwatch

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to measure the elapsed time between two points of my code.
I tried to use the clock_gettime function in the code below, but it is not giving the expected results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    struct timespec start, finish;
    long unsigned int elapsed;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);

    sleep(1);

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &finish);

    elapsed = finish.tv_nsec;
    elapsed = elapsed - start.tv_nsec;

    printf("%lu\n", elapsed);
}
```

I was expecting something close to 1.000.000.000 but it prints values like: 122360, 220942, 205456, 225053.
What I'm I doing wrong? Is there a better way of measuring the elapsed time with a resolution of at least 0.1 seconds?

Comment: With the nanoseconds, you are just looking at the fractional part. You need to use both the seconds and the nanoseconds together to get the time measurement.

Comment: If you start at 1.90 second and end at 2.10 seconds, your math works out to you calculating  0.9 - 0.1 = 0.8 seconds (or 800000000) nano seconds. That's not right, it should be 0.2 seconds. Think about your way of doing math.